# getInitialState was defined on Loginpanel(//Name of my component), a plain JavaScript class

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flux, reactjs-flux

Hello i am quite new to react, i try to remove this error, but nothing works for me.

Please help me with it.
My component is look like this.

error is "getInitialState was defined on Loginpanel, a plain JavaScript class. This is only supported for classes created using React.createClass. Did you mean to define a state property instead?"

```
 export default withRouter(class Loginpanel extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {
        datas1: [],
        NotWorking: "UserName OR Password is Wrong",
       // comments: AppStore.getAll(),
    };
}

getStateFromStore()  {
    return {
        comments: AppStore.getAll()
    }
}


componentWillMount() {



    firebase.database().ref("UserPassworddata/").once("value", (snapshot) => {

        var datas1 = []
        snapshot.forEach((data1) =>
        {

            datas1.push( {

                username: data1.val().Username,
                password: data1.val().Password,

            });

        });

        this.setState ({
            datas1: datas1,
        });

    });
}





onChange() {
    this.setState(comments);
}

getInitialState() {
    return comments;
}

componentDidMount() {
    AppStore.addChangeListener(this.onChange.bind(this));
    console.log(AppStore.addChangeListener(this.onChange.bind(this)));
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    AppStore.removeChangeListener(this.onChange.bind(this));
    console.log(AppStore.removeChangeListener(this.onChange.bind(this)));
}

checkCred(){

    //AppActions.addItem('Yes this is done by me');
    var details_array = this.state.datas1 ;
    console.log(details_array);
    for(var i=0; i < details_array.length; i++){
        var currentObject = details_array[i];
        if (this.email.value == currentObject.username && this.password.value == currentObject.password){
            console.log('yes done it');


            this.props.router.push('Index');
            AppActions.createComment(currentObject.username,currentObject.password);

            var dis = this.state.comments
            console.log(dis);

        }
        else{

            console.log('sorry man not working');
        }
    }
}

render() {

    return (
        <div>

            <Link to="/"> <button className="button1" bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large"> Login </button></Link>
            <Link to="Signup"> <button className="button1" bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large"> Signup </button></Link>



           <div id="Login">
            Email:
               <input ref={(e) => this.email = e} className="form-fields" name="email" required="required" type="email"   placeholder="User Name" /><br/>
            Password:

               <input ref={(f) => this.password = f} className="form-fields" name="password" required="required" type="password"   placeholder="Password" /><br/>
             <button onClick={this.checkCred.bind(this)} className="button1" bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large" > Submit </button>




             </div>
           </div>
         )
      }
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the es6 class you don't use `getInitialState` anymore, instead you use the following in your constructor

```js
this.state = {
    comments: []
}
```

You almost had it! Just need to remove the `getInitialState` block and uncomment your "comments" field in your constructor :)

Comment: you increase my confidence of problem solving.. thanks from my heart

Comment: :D 

oh... you shouldn't be getting that error if there is no `getInitialState` method in your class - try restarting the react-native packager and try again - if you get the same error - update your answer (don't overwrite the existing code example) with your new code and ill take a look

Comment: man... i found it.. thanks lot.. just left with getInitialState....  it works. all good thanks

Comment: Awesome! no probs! :)